# In SQL Server 2016,If we create Memory Optimized Table

Tags: sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016,If we create Memory Optimized Table(i.e create table on RAM ),will the table data persist if I restart my computer?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a memory optimized table you set a table option: `WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON)`. That table option has a second parameter `DURABILITY` which either can be: `SCHEMA_AND_DATA` in which case the data is persisted, or `SCHEMA_ONLY` in which case only the schema is persisted. Default is `SCHEMA_AND_DATA`.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql).

Niels

Comment: OK ..Got it Thanks.

Comment: I think..We need to move to memory optimized table based on the RAM size and the size of the business data.If the size of business data is more that RAM,then we cannot store in  RAM?.Iam I right in saying that?

Comment: @user3653116 - that is correct. Here is a link to estimating memory requirements:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/estimate-memory-requirements-for-memory-optimized-tables